# What is the type of this function in Scala?

Tags: scala

What function type should I specify instead `AnyRef`?

```
case class Fun() {
  val anonFun: AnyRef = { 
    (x: Int) => x + 1
  }
}
```

My calling code:

```
val f = Fun()
val result = f.anonFun(1)
```

**PS**

As @jarandaf said the return type of this specific function is `Function1[Int, Int]`. But who can explain me why not `Function1[Int]`?

Comment: none at all, let it be done by the type inference.

Comment: Yes, I know it is possible to use `val anonFun = (x: Int) => x + 1`. But I want to specify a return type.

Comment: The return type is `function`. So I want to know what the type fits this `function`.

Comment: a fuction with one argument and one return value has two generic arguments. The return value, and the argument. Bth you can always take the repl and write an expression. The repl tells you the exact type of that expression and you just need to copy paste it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is able to infer that. If you want to manually specify it (e.g. you are writing some kind of public API), you can use syntactic sugar for function types:

```
val anonFun : Int => Int = (x: Int) => x + 1
```

A shorter option would be:

```
val anonFun : Int => Int = _ + 1
```

This actually translates to a `Function1[Int,Int]` instance.

Comment: Seems so. It works fine: `val anonFun: Function1[Int, Int] = (x: Int) => x + 1`

Comment: But I don't understand why it is so. Why not `Function1[Int]`?

Comment: Because it takes an Int and returns an Int

Comment: Functions are instances of `FunctionN[-T1,...,-TN,+R]` trait, where the first N type variables are the corresponding function parameters types (in this example, there's only one parameter of type `Int`). The last type variable corresponds to the function result type, in this case, also `Int`. This explains the function type `Function1[Int,Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

The function takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`, so its type is `Int => Int`.

A more interesting implementation without repeating the parameter type:

```
val anonFun: Int => Int = { _ + 1 }
```